# loop data in textbox from serial data vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm newbie to VB.net. my case is, i need to display data from serial port to text box. In continuous loop. How do i do that?

I have wrote simple program to display the data. i can display the data once in the textbox, but not continuously.

serialport1 is where i get data from port 1. serialport2 is data from port 2.

```
SerialPort2.Write("!12,F" & vbCr)
```

data "!11,F" and "!12,F" is a command to my 2 device.

TextBox2.Text and TextBox5.Text is where i want to continuously display my data.

here is the code;

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form2

    Dim myPort As Array
    Dim myport1 As Array
    Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal [text] As String) 'Added to prevent threading errors during receiveing of data
    '------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        myport1 = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(myPort)
        ComboBox2.Items.AddRange(myport1)

        btnwrite.Enabled = False

    End Sub
    '------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btninit.Click


        SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591) ' convert to ascii
        SerialPort1.PortName = ComboBox1.Text
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = TextBox3.Text
        SerialPort1.Open()

        SerialPort2.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591) ' convert to ascii
        SerialPort2.PortName = ComboBox2.Text
        SerialPort2.BaudRate = TextBox3.Text
        SerialPort2.Open()


        btninit.Enabled = False
        btnwrite.Enabled = True
        btnwrite2.Enabled = True
        btnclose.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    '------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnwrite.Click

            SerialPort1.Write("!11,F" & vbCr) 'concatenate with \n

    End Sub


    Private Sub btnwrite2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnwrite2.Click

        SerialPort2.Write("!12,F" & vbCr) 'concatenate with \n

    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived

        ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())

    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort2_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort2.DataReceived

        ReceivedText1(SerialPort2.ReadExisting())


    End Sub

    Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String) 'input from ReadExisting


        If Me.TextBox2.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.TextBox2.Text &= [text] 'append text

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ReceivedText1(ByVal [text] As String) 'input from ReadExisting


        If Me.TextBox5.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText1)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.TextBox5.Text &= [text] 'append text
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnclose_click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnclose.Click

        SerialPort1.Close()
        SerialPort2.Close()

        btninit.Enabled = True
        btnwrite.Enabled = False
        btnwrite2.Enabled = False
        btnclose.Enabled = False

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I think you should use a background worker with a timer.

Comment: Make sure you are receiving text data not binary data.

Comment: in addition to a background worker also a simple winform timer could be useful for you. You can set a timer interval based on your needs and read your serial port in timer.tick private sub